# Protostar Template makes mobile version right module moved to the bottom and shows white space

Tags: joomla-3.5

My website is Joomla 3.5. I use Protostar Template, but in mobile version it shows the whole right modules moved to the bottom with white space. How can I fix for this? I am very bad at coding. Thank you very much.

[image: First Page]

[image: Roll Down]

Comment: Please add an screenshot or the URL of your proyect, this with the purpose to be able to help a little more.

Comment: Please also update to Joomla 3.6

Comment: Should I do backup before updating to Joomla 3.6?

Comment: Will there be any problem updating to Joomla 3.6 ? I just pasted on images. Should I just fix the right side to without white space, but keep the modules at the downside? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Yes backup the site before updating just incase.

Answer (score 1):

You've suggested using

```
html  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

But for centering you should use

```
html  {
  ...
  margin: 0px auto;
  ...
}
```

instead

---

Also from what I can see: some of modules at your screen shots must have content that going beyond a viewport.